# How to get values from a facebook login button and pass it to another activity

Tags: android, facebook, button, authentication, parameter-passing

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
LoginButton fbloginButton;
CallbackManager callbackManager;
private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
private static final int REQUEST_SIGNUP = 0;

@BindView(R.id.input_email) EditText _emailText;
@BindView(R.id.input_password) EditText _passwordText;
@BindView(R.id.btn_login) Button _loginButton;
@BindView(R.id.link_signup) TextView _signupLink;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    fbloginButton=(LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    fbloginButton.setReadPermissions("email","public_profile");
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    fbloginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            String userid=loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();
            GraphRequest graphRequest=GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                    displayUserInfo(object);
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters=new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields","first_name,last_name,email");
            graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
            graphRequest.executeAsync();


        }
        public void displayUserInfo(JSONObject object)
        {
            String first_name="",last_name="",email="";
            try {
                ***first_name=object.getString(first_name);
                ***last_name=object.getString(last_name);
                ***email=object.getString(email);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
```

This is my code which is LoginActivity.java

i want to get values specified *** and pass it to next actvity in the respective fields. The next activity has five fields which are name,address,email, mobile number and password. i want to get the values first name and last name and pass it to name field and email address to email field.

I am a beginner in android developing.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend telling people that they have to help you right now. That usually has just the opposite affect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a listener that will start the next activity; for example, do you want the next activity to start at the onComplete() or at onSuccess() or somewhere else?
Anywhere you want to trigger the next activity, put the below code there;

```
startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,   NextActivity.class)
                           .putExtra("firstName", first_name)
                           .putExtra("lastName",last_name)
                           .putExtra("email",email)
);
```